# Return не прерывает функцию и возвращает None

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, return

Есть список списков списков. 
Необходимо узнать, в каком именно списке лежит искомое значение.

В стеке функций для поиска значения в списках запускается рекурсия, в результате которой в return-е вызывается соседняя функция, которая возвращает имя переменной-списка, в котором лежит искомое значение.

Однако return не прерывает работу родительской функции и в какой-то момент обнуляется, в результате чего возвращается значение None.

Через print всё прекрасно принтуется, но возвращаться не хочет. На визуализаторе гонял полдня, так и не понял в чём проблема. Что я делаю не так?

```
integers = [7, 32, 657]
mix = [8, (345,353), 'sdfg']

floats = [3.345, 123.67, 435.64]
strings = ['345', 'dfas', 'dfshs']

rhymes = ['fast', 'must', 'dust', 'rust']
rus_rhymes = ['юля', 'пуля', 'гуля', 'пилюля']

nums = [integers, floats]
poems = [rhymes, rus_rhymes]
others = [strings, mix]

global_dictionary = [nums, poems, others]

def display(var):
    for name, value in list(globals().items()):
        if var is value:
            return name


def list_src(lst, value):
    for i in lst:
        if type(i) != list and value == i:
            print(display(lst))
            return display(lst)

        elif type(i) == list: 
            list_src(i, value)


def main():
    print(list_src(global_dictionary, 'dust'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Вывод программы:    
# rhymes - через print в теле функции list_src()
# None - через return
```

Comment: У вас list(globals().items()) является None, поэтому display() возвращает None

Comment: @MazZz3R, display возвращает rhymes, причём почему-то дважды (если судить по визуализатору).

Comment: list_src вернет None, если первое условие ни разу не выполнится, и цикл дойдет до конца.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
integers = [7, 32, 657]
mix = [8, (345,353), 'sdfg']

floats = [3.345, 123.67, 435.64]
strings = ['345', 'dfas', 'dfshs']

rhymes = ['fast', 'must', 'dust', 'rust']
rus_rhymes = ['юля', 'пуля', 'гуля', 'пилюля']

nums = [integers, floats]
poems = [rhymes, rus_rhymes]
others = [strings, mix]

global_dictionary = [nums, poems, others]

def display(variable):
    for name, value in globals().items():
        try:
            if variable in value:
                return name
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return "Значение не содержится, ни в одном из списков"

def main():
    print(display("dust"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А по умолчанию функция возвращает None

Comment: Эмм... да, с одной стороны вы правы, но с другой стороны зачем он там, если в элифе вызывается рекурсия, которая должна начать весь предыдущий процесс с ифа? Что там по-вашему может возвращаться? Я не вижу нужного результата возврата из элифа. Если стартовать весь цикл через while, то получается бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Как можно изменить цикл? Я пробовал его переписать в "одну ветку" без доп.условий - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Что должен делать скрипт опишите словами

Comment: Рекурсия и цикл for не уместно на мой взгляд

Comment: В первом же абзаце написано: "Есть список списков списков. Необходимо узнать, в каком именно списке лежит искомое значение." Это недостаточно ясное описание? Скрипт именно это и делает. В принте он выводит ожидаемый результат, в ретёрне - нет.

Comment: Если более подробно, то задача list_src прогнать данное ей значение через все уровни списков, начиная с основного, и найти соответствие в одном из них. Для пущего понимания назовите списки не списками, а категориями и подкатегориями. Одни включены в другие. Мы не знаем, ни глубину, ни ширину ветвления категорий. Нужно найти название той конечной (или начальной - как вам угодно) категории, которая содержит искомую строку. Гарантируется, что искомая строка где-то зашита.

Comment: Узнать есть ли в во всех этих массивах "dust"?

Comment: Узнать, В КАКОМ из этих массивов dust

Answer (score 0):

**Это, конечно, не решение проблемы с непрерыванием функции через первый return в рекурсивном цикле**, но сама проблема получения нужного значения в принципе решается через следующий костыль:

- до объявления функций можно создать пустую глобальную переменную с
  любым значением;
- учитывая, что принт делается правильно, то вместо принта и ретёрна
  можно вызвать эту глобальную переменную и записать в неё полученное
  значение.

После этого можно тягать это значение через переменную.

```
integers = [7, 32, 657]
mix = [8, (345,353), 'sdfg']

floats = [3.345, 123.67, 435.64]
strings = ['345', 'dfas', 'dfshs']

rhymes = ['fast', 'must', 'dust', 'rust']
rus_rhymes = ['юля', 'пуля', 'гуля', 'пилюля']

nums = [integers, floats]
poems = [rhymes, rus_rhymes]
others = [strings, mix]

global_dictionary = [nums, poems, others]

LIST_NAME = ''

def display(var):
    for name, value in list(globals().items()):
        if var is value:
            return name


def list_src(lst, value):
    for i in lst:
        if type(i) != list and value == i:
            global LIST_NAME
            LIST_NAME = display(lst)

        elif type(i) == list: 
            list_src(i, value)


def main():
    list_src(global_dictionary, 'dust')
    print(LIST_NAME)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Вывод программы:
# rhymes - принт из корня программы (main), т.е. уже после отработки всех остальных функций.
```

Comment: Использование глобальных переменных - плохой тон.

Comment: Если это работает как надо, то кого это волнует?

Comment: Лишь бы тебе нравилось:-)

Comment: Так, стоп-игра! Приношу свои извинения. Я как-то за этими комментариями совершенно пропустил то, что вы дали решение в коде. Т.е. проще говоря, я написал лишнюю функцию? Достаточно использовать дисплей и всё?! =\ Хех...Забавно. 

Большое СПАСИБО за помощь!

Comment: Если честно я не совсем понимаю где такое может понадобится я просто исходя из задания решил так.